# Why in my blazor page it seems dbcontext became read-only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, blazor

I have a Blazor page like the following:

```
@inject IDbContextFactory<MyContext> DbFactory

<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnSubmit="@Submit" FormName="create">
   ...
   ...
   ... 
   <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Create</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
   ...

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        using var dbcontext = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

        MyObject c = new MyObject
           {
              MyMember1="abc",
              MyMember2="123"
           };

        dbcontext.MyObjects.Add(c);

        await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

In `Program.cs`, the factory is declared like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlazorAppContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'BlazorAppContext' not found.")));
```

`MyObject` is declared as follows:

```
public class MyBaseObject
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string? MyMember1{ get; set; }
    public string? MyMember2 { get; set; }

    public MyBaseObject()
    {
    }

    public MyBaseObject(MyBaseObject mybaseObject)
    {
        MyMember1 = mybaseObject.MyMember1;
        MyMember2 = mybaseObject.MyMember2;
    }

    public void AssignBase(MyBaseObject mybaseObject)
    {
        MyMember1 = mybaseObject.MyMember1;
        MyMember2 = mybaseObject.MyMember2;
    }
}

public class MyObject : MyBaseObject
{
    public MyObject() : base()
    {
    }

    public MyObject(MyBaseObject baseobject) : base(baseobject)
    {
    }
}
```

The object 'c' is created correctly, before adding c to `dbcontext.MyObjects`, `MyObjects` contains two objects correctly taken from the SQL Server Express database.

After `Add(c)`, the content of `dbcontext.MyObjects` is the very same as before, so with only two objects. It seems `dbcontext` ignores the `Add` statement or it is readonly.

In the `DatabaseInitiator` class, it works fine and the database is correctly populated with initial data.

I expected to have `dbcontext.MyObjects` owning three elements, with my 'c' added to the existing two, but this doesn't happen.

So, why it seems my `dbcontext` in the Blazor page is read-only ?

Thank you all.

**Edit:**
It seems I have solved. I added `dbcontext.Entry(Model.CurrentUser).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` before `SaveChanges`. But really I don't understand why a user gets changed. I'm not doing any change on Users.
Special thanks to @StevePy who put me on the right path.

Comment: To confirm, this is Blazor Server, not Blazor Web Assembly? (AFAIK EF isn't an option for Web Assembly given it will run entirely in client sandbox) When you check for items added, are you checking the DbContext or the database directly? For instance add: `var count = dbcontext.MyObjects.Count()` before the `.Add(c)` call, then `count = dbContext.MyObjects.Count()` after the SaveChanges.  Do both of these report "2"? If you are checking the database for the added record it is possible the runtime connection string is going to a different DB instance.

Comment: I agree with @StevePy there is no evidence here that this is a "readonly" behaviour at all. After calling `SaveChangesAsync` you could even load all the items and write them out to the console. There is no evidence here of how the items are verified, if OP is using SSMS or has another page to load the data. If it is another page, is the data cached, or did it actually reload from the database? The only other quirk I can see would be with the inheritance model, but if that failed or was misconfigured, I would expect to see exceptions.

Comment: The problem I see is before the `SaveChangeAsync`. As @StevePy said. I ran in debug mode and watched `dbcontext.MyObjects`, the content is the same before and after `.Add(c)`. Shouldn't I see a different content ? @ChrisSchaller I also had some doubts about the inheritance, but from the `InitDatabase` function it all work fine. Any additional clue ?

Comment: If you are checking the count *before* calling `SaveChanges` then no, the new item will not appear. The reason is that calling `Count` will execute a query against the database for the count of all rows. Your new row won't come back as part of that until after `SaveChanges` commits it. The new record will be part of the `.MyObjects.Local` cache and the change tracker in an Added state, but it is not counted as being a real record until it is comitted. If you are still seeing a count of 2 after SaveCHanges then we will need to see how the DbContext/DbSet are configured.

Comment: @StevePy we are getting closer. This explains the reason why I still see 2, but now the real exception is raised at `SaveChanges`:  there is a primary key violation because `SaveChanges` tries to save back to database the complete set of elements present in `dbcontext` and not only the newly added. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @StevePy update: the exception I get is: `SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. The duplicate key value is (cf27fdab-ec74-44cb-9f13-1f1cc31ac2bf).`
In `dbcontext` there is a member `User` that I read, but don't update or add. How could it be possible that it tries to write a `User` even if I don't touch it ?

Comment: See my answer below around the untracked reference. You are likely setting directly or indirectly a user reference on the new entity like a CreatedBy/ModifiedBy or such, but that user reference isn't a tracked reference in the DbContext. Any references like this need to be loaded/tracked before being associated to a new object being saved otherwise they too are treated as inserts. If you still have an issue identifying the issue, update your question with the real entity you are trying to insert.

Comment: It seems I have solved. I added `dbcontext.Entry(Model.CurrentUser).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` before `SaveChanges`. But really I don't understand why a user gets changed. I'm not doing any change on Users. Special thanks to @StevePy who put me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding PK Violations on `SaveChanges`: These are commonly caused by one of two things, PKs that aren't set up to operate as Identities and have not been given a unique ID in code, or attempting to associate references to existing rows using untracked copies of those related entities.

**Identity PKs**

By default most database providers & EF will recognize `int`/`long` properties named "Id" or "{EntityName}Id"/"{EntityName}_Id" (i.e. MyObjectId) as identity columns which will be populated by the database on Save. However some databases such as in-memory databases don't provide this capability so the Identity behaviour is ignored. This can result in errors when it tries inserting rows with an ID of 0 where a row already exists with that ID. If you were using a non-conventional PK name such as "MyObjectKey" then you would need to identify that as the PK and as an identity column. Since yours is named "Id" that should not be the case so long as you are using a database that does support identity columns.

**Untracked References**

This would involve creating a new MyObject that has a reference to another existing entity. For example if a MyObject has a reference to a Status which is an entity pointing to a Statuses lookup table and you did something like:

```
using var dbcontext = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

MyObject c = new MyObject
{
    MyMember1="abc",
    MyMember2="123", 
    Status = new Status { StatusId == 1 } // "New" status
};

dbcontext.MyObjects.Add(c);

await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This would result in a PK error. While you might intend to be only inserting the MyObject and referencing an existing Status of "New" /w ID 1, that status is not tracked by the DbContext so it will be interpreted as a new. This includes cases where you might pass a Status "entity" into this method, such as  a reference coming back from a web client.

Instead, you want to ensure that any references to existing records in the DB are first loaded and tracked by the DbContext. This ensures it knows to associate the new entity to an existing reference, not attempt to insert a new reference:

```
var status = dbContext.Statuses.Single(x => x.StatusId == 1); // "New status"
MyObject c = new MyObject
{
    MyMember1="abc",
    MyMember2="123", 
    Status = status
};
```